# Finding the second derivative of a first derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

so I have a $ \frac{ dy}{dx}=\frac{-2x+y}{2y-x} $ from the original equation $ \ x^2+y^2-xy=1 \ $.

I have to find the second derivative given a coordinate point $\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}},2\sqrt{
\frac{1}{3}})\right)$.
Here is my work:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{(2y-x)(-2+y')-(-2x+y)(2y'-1)}{(2y-x)^2} $$

$$=\frac{(2y-x)\left(-2+\frac{-2x+y}{2y-x}\right)-(-2x+y)(\frac{-4x+2y}{2y-x}-1)}{(2y-x)^2}$$

then I started plugging in,

$$=\frac{\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(-x+\frac{-2\sqrt{1/3}+2\sqrt{1/3}}{4\sqrt{1/3}-\sqrt{1/3}}\right)-[(-2\sqrt{1/3}+2\sqrt{1/3}\left(2[\frac{-2\sqrt{1/3}+2\sqrt{1/3}}{4\sqrt{1/3}-\sqrt{1/3}}]-1\right)]}{(4\sqrt{1/3}-\sqrt{1/3})^2}$$

Some of the expressions cancelled out to be 0, so I ended up with

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{3\sqrt{1/3}}{(3\sqrt{1/3})^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$$
However, this wasn't the right answer. Is there an easier approach or something wrong with my calculation? Thank you.

Comment: This is completely unintelligible!  You need to edit this using latex.  You can find the tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I have made a first cut at making this a _bit_ more readable; I don't have time at the moment to pick through all the "sqrts" and such...

Answer (score 1):

I can't read the question, so I'll give the second derivative. Use the quotient rule:
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{(2y-x)\left(-2+\frac{-2x+y}{2y-x}\right)-(-2x+y)\left(2\frac{-2x+y}{2y-x}-x\right)}{(2y-x)^2}$$
Substitute the given $(x,y)$ coordinate to find the second derivative there.

Comment: Remember $y$ depends on $x$, so you need to use implicit differentiation.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Isn't that what I've done?

Comment: Did you? I just assumed you applied the quotient rule straight, but I see you substituted in for $y'$. +1

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Thanks!